# My attempt to grab the hrefs from a bunch of <a> tags: Explain where I'm going wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

From a `tbody` element

```
<tbody id="results">
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"><a href="/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-roman_column.png">/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-roman_column.png</a></td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>Azure</td>
      <td>roman_column.png</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"><a href="/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-runphp.cmd">/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-runphp.cmd</a></td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>Azure</td>
      <td>runphp.cmd</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"><a href="/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-runphp.cmd">/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-runphp.cmd</a></td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>Azure</td>
      <td>runphp.cmd</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"><a href="/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-Picture1.png">/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-Picture1.png</a></td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>Azure</td>
      <td>Picture1.png</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"><a href="/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-vertical-align-scrnsht.png">/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-vertical-align-scrnsht.png</a></td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>Azure</td>
      <td>vertical-align-scrnsht.png</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"><a href="/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-vertical-align-scrnsht.png">/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-vertical-align-scrnsht.png</a></td>
      <td>Microsoft</td>
      <td>Azure</td>
      <td>vertical-align-scrnsht.png</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

my procedure attempts to grab the `href`s and stick them in an array called `links`:

```
        var resultRows = $('#results > tr > td > a');
        for (var thisAnchor in resultRows) links.push($(this).attr('href'));
        for (var thisLink in links) console.log(thisLink); // test
```

But that test is logging

```
0
1
.
.
.
171
172
```

to the console rather than the expected

```
/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-roman_column.png
/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-runphp.cmd
/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-runphp.cmd
/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-Picture1.png
/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-vertical-align-scrnsht.png
/../../Assets/Microsoft-Azure-vertical-align-scrnsht.png
```

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use jQuery .each, like this:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
links.push(href);
console.log(href);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your selector was yeilding no elements, so change to

```
$('#results [href]')
```

Second, use `.each` instead of the for loop

```
$('#results [href]').each(function(){
    links.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Finally, change

```
for (var thisLink in links) console.log(thisLink);
```

to

```
for (var thisLink in links) console.log(links[thisLink]);
```

When you iterate a foreach loop in javascript like

```
for(var key in collection)
```

key, is the actual key or index in this case because you have an array

See it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1kjfqcth/2/)

Comment: @CantGetLaid, yes in this case

Comment: @CantGetLaid, see my corrected and update answer/fiddle

Comment: You should do the same for the anchor  for loop: resultRows[thisAnchor].attr('href'); instead of $(this).attr('href');

Comment: This is not a good solution, it's assuming that there are no other links on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid. You have an unclosed `input` tag.

Next your `tbody` needs to be wrapped by a `table` tag

Then if you are looking for an array of `hrefs`, you should use the jQquery.map function.

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/p6h7o32m/